# unable to pass values from vp

Tags: apex, visualforce

**VF page:-**

```
<apex:page controller="select_update" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
           <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!a.NumberOfEmployees}"/>
           <apex:column headerValue="Phone" >
               <apex:outputField value="{!a.Phone}">
               <apex:inlineEditSupport />
               </apex:outputField>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Industry" >
               <apex:outputField value="{!a.Industry}">
               <apex:inlineEditSupport />
               </apex:outputField> 
           </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
            <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!delete_record}" >    
                 <apex:param name="idParam" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!idchosen}"/>
            </apex:commandbutton>
             </apex:column>

           </apex:pageBlockTable>
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
               <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!update_data}"/>      
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>

       </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex:-**

```
public class select_update
{
public list<account> acc{get;set;}
public list<account> del{get;set;}
public string idchosen{get;set;}

public select_update ()
{
 acc = new list<account>();
 acc = [SELECT Name,Phone,Industry,NumberOfEmployees FROM account];
}
public void update_data()
{
 update acc;
}

public void delete_record()
{

    del= [SELECT id FROM account WHERE id = :idchosen];
    delete del;
}
}
```

Delete Functionality not working properly

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54524/discussion-on-question-by-ragul-unable-to-pass-values-from-vp).

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is your `id` was not getting transferred to controller since you were refreshing the page. I've modified your Controller little bit. Instead of refreshing whole page ideally you should `reRender` block in which you've made changes. Below is VF page code:

```
<apex:page controller="select_update" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
        <apex:form id="form">
           <apex:pageBlock id="block">
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
               <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
               <apex:column value="{!a.NumberOfEmployees}"/>
               <apex:column headerValue="Phone" >
                   <apex:outputField value="{!a.Phone}">
                   <apex:inlineEditSupport />
                   </apex:outputField>
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Industry" >
                   <apex:outputField value="{!a.Industry}">
                   <apex:inlineEditSupport />
                   </apex:outputField> 
               </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!delete_record}" reRender="form">    
                     <apex:param name="idchosen" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!idchosen}" />
                </apex:commandbutton>

                 </apex:column>

               </apex:pageBlockTable>
               <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
                   <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!update_data}"/>      
               </apex:pageBlockButtons>

           </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

And you Apex class:

```
public class select_update
{
  public list<account> acc{get{
      list<account> acc = new list<account>();
     acc = [SELECT Name,Phone,Industry,NumberOfEmployees FROM account LIMIT 9999];
     return acc;
  }set;}

  public list<account> del{get;set;}
  public String idchosen{
        get;
        // *** setter is NOT being called ***
        set {
            idchosen= value;

        }
    }

  public select_update ()
  {


  }
  public void update_data()
  {
    update acc;
  }

  public void delete_record()
  {

      del= [SELECT id FROM account WHERE id = :idchosen];
      delete del;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a long history of usage `<apex:commandButton>` with the custom parameter `<apex:param>`, Its a known bug from salesforce and from a long time, even when I started learning salesforce. 
In order to use `<apex:param>` with `<apex:commandButton>` to send/assign custom parameter to controller, we use a hacky or tricky solution, we need to specify `rerender` attribute of `<apex:commandButton>` by adding a fake/dummy panel.

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!delete_record}" rerender="dummyPanel">
```

here is the reference:
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

Comment: I agree your answer is correct but I guess it's partial because  it introduces a known bug of Updated Account list after deletion of a particular account record. OP will likely expect that after rerendering a `dummyPanel`, `pageblocktable` should contain updated list of `Accounts`.